# Hover problem on Drupal menu

Tags: html, css, drupal, menu

I have a menu and when the user hovers the menu, the submenu appears. Only, the submenu disappears when you're not hovering the text.

Let me try to make it clear using images.
**When hovering the text (how it should be):**
[image] leads to this 
[image]

**When hovering the area near the text:**
[image] leads to this
[image]

And to make it even more complicate, it only happens in Safari en Chrome (the webkit engine I guess) and it doesn't do this all the time :)

I'm guessing it's a css problem, but anyone know where to look?

(Oh, and it's a Drupal website, so I don't know it this plays along...)

**UPDATE**
This is how the HTML looks like: 
[image]

Comment: where is the submenu in the code?

Comment: the first `ul` is the main menu, the `li` is the submenu and sometimes there is a new `ul` and `li`inside the shown `li`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are modules that can do this for you, such as Nice Menus.

The submenu is probably not a child of the parent menu in the DOM. It's probably something like this:

```
<ul id="parent">
    <li>menu item</li>
</ul>
<ul id="submenu">
    <li>menu item</li>
</ul>
```

So when you hover over the submenu, mouseLeave/mouseOut is triggered on the parent.
You can solve this in multiple ways. One is to restructure your HTML such that the submenu is in the parent:

```
<ul id="parent">
    <li>menu item
        <ul id="submenu">
            <li>menu item</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

or to detect/save the hovered item state in JavaScript. To do that, one possible way is to save the using either a jQuery data object or add a class (e.g. "on") to the menu you hover over and use sibling/child selectors to detect if you're in a submenu. If you're not in the parent or a submenu, remove the "on" class.

There's many ways to do this, both in JavaScript/HTML/CSS and using Drupal Modules. Show some code if you're still confused.

Comment: Actually, I'm using the module Nice Menus. Should I take a look to this one?

Comment: I added some HTML. The code doesn't looks like you said. I don't think I can restructure the HTML (cause it's Drupal)